# What's the difference between in calculation or in the calculation?

Tags: american-english

The scenario is I am going to show how to process many uncertainty terms in the calculation, but the title of the slide should be "uncertainties in calculation" or "uncertainties in the calculation?" I feel it is more appropriate to use the latter one, but what's the subtle difference between these two?[image]

It's about: When we need to do a calculation on the quantities that have uncertainties, how do we do it? For the case including addition or subtraction... Please refer to part of the slide I uploaded.

Comment: Is the slide talking about one specific calculation ("uncertainties in the calculation"), or about the principles of calculating things more generally ("uncertainties in calculation")?

Comment: It depends what is meant by ‘a equals b plus-or-minus c’.  What does this mean for any value of b and c such neither of them is zero?  If both b and c have non-zero values, then surely ‘a = b plus-or-minus c’ is not a well-formed formula?

Answer (score -1):

> "uncertainties in calculation" or "uncertainties in the calculation?"

I would guess that you wish to show, that

"uncertainties should be considered when making (Doing) a calculation"

But what you have written is

**In the calculation** by which you mean the uncertainties form part of the calculation for example x=y*z-(uncertainties) where uncertainties are Blah Blah Blah!

**in calculation**, which is the act of calculating something, so this means you are not confident that the calculation has been done in a correct manner.

How about calling the slide **Calculations; Consideration of Uncertainties** This should cover all bases, no matter what your meaning is.

> **calculation**: noun;  the process of using information you already have and adding, taking away, multiplying, or dividing numbers to judge the number or amount of something: [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/calculation)